# google maps v3 marker title property

Tags: google-maps-api-3, title, marker

In my function I am looping through an array of states and placing markers in the center of each state. I want each marker tooltip to display its specific information. However, for some reason when I mouse over the markers a tooltip doesn't popup over any of them even though I instantiated the marker with the title property.

see code below:

```
mark = new google.maps.Marker({          
        map: map,             
        position: center,
        title:inspStates[i].name+ "<br/>"+"total: "+inspStates[i].totalInsp+ "<br/>"+ info
        });
```

what is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set the disableDefaultUI to true which apparently caused the tooltips not to be shown. When I reenabled it all the markers had a tooltip with the proper information.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have error in your code

   title:inspStates[i].name+ "
   "+"total: "+inspStates[i].totalInsp+ "
   "+ info;

The trailing semicolon is mistaken. You are defining an object property but not the simple variable.
2. According to your code all markers will be shown at same place(Of course, if `center` is not being defined each loop iteration)

```
position: center
```

Maybe there should be something like this `inspStates[i].position`?

**UPD**

Here is my code sample.

```
var places=[
            {
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5220975, -0.1702880859375),
               name: 'first place'
            },
            {
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.51, -0.1714),
               name: 'second place'
            },
            {
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.52205918460975, -0.17380859375),
               name: 'third place'
            }
        ];
for(var i=0, len=places.length; i<len; i++)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: places[i].position,
         title: places[i].name
    });
}
```

Maybe it will be helpfull. Three markers with predifined titles has been shown by this code. Is your code like my? Also one question: Is variable `center` from your code being changed each loop itaration. I have talked about it but oyu haven't commented it.
Could you please post your code sample to get more help?

Comment: one marker is being shown at the center of each state as planned bu even after I removed the trailing semicolon the tooltip doesn't appear when I mouseover